# Pass parameters in cakephp function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

```
$this->requestAction("/survey/responsethereuser/qid:$qid,uid:$uid,sid:$sid");
```

In my controller

```
function responsethereuser($qid = null, $uid=null, $sid=null)
```

It is showing on taking value of qid

```
$qid=1,uid:3,sid:1
```

How to get all the parameter values correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->requestAction("/survey/responsethereuser/", array('qid'=>$qid, 'uid'=>$uid, 'sid'=>$sid));
```